# Issue with UINavigationBar large title while popping to non-large translucent bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios-animations

I am implementing UINavigationBar for two UIViewController: assume ControllerA and ControllerB.

**ControllerA** has translucent UINavigationBar with backgroundColor = .clear property.

**ControllerB** has ***prefersLargeTitles*** enabled property and white background.

I should push and pop from **ControllerA** -> **ControllerB**. Here the code I've implemented in **controllerA** life cycle methods:

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        }

        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear

        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
            .font: FontFamily.SFProRounded.bold.font(size: 18),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ]
    }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

            navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
                .font: FontFamily.SFProRounded.bold.font(size: 22),
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
        }
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
            .font: FontFamily.SFProRounded.bold.font(size: 18),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.black
        ]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    }
```

**Below** the issues I've had on different iOS versions:

1. ***Version < iOS 13***

Incorrect animation and title color while tap back button for controller dismissing. Video here:  https://youtu.be/1g9esUgYDK8

2. ***Version == iOS 13***

Large title not moving with dismissed controller during pop animation. Video here: https://youtu.be/25k3oz2_wcE

How to solve it? Thank you in advance

Comment: override viewWillDisapper() in B class and again set normal navigation bar there. 
It help to resolve incorrect animation.

Comment: It doesn't fix the issues

Comment: I have faced same issue earlier but i have done above change and it resolved.

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately It didn't help.. Looks like I'm making transition between two UINavigationBar states completely wrong

Comment: You can try with override `viewWillDisappear` in `ControllerB` and set navigation changes back for `ControllerA`. Remove the nav settings from `viewWillAppear` and set it into `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @FarhanAmjad its also not working :( I suppose that problem in my code, not in methods where code is calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've added

```swift
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
}
```

in **ViewDidLoad** of ***ControllerB*** and

```swift
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```

in **ViewDidLoad** of ***ControllerA***
and it works as I expected.

Note that you need to set **prefersLargeTitles** only one time, preferably when opening the application